# LIMIT based on COUNT of DISTINCT `foreign_key` so far

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a union of 2 tables 'sites' and 'trucks' (ordered by `distance`). The recordset looks like:

[image]

I need to fetch all rows until I reach to the specific (n) number of unique company_ids, starting from row 1.

So, if I a get something like the following: [image]

Then I can make a simple query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM union_recordset where distinct_company_id_count_so_far < (3 + 1);
-- where n = 3
```

and get the desired result of:

[image]

Comment: You have tagged the question with different databases.  You should tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: For this type of questions, it is better to build your table and sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ so then you and who answer the question can test the solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database supports `count(distinct)` as a window function:

```
select ur.*,
       count(distinct company_id) over (order by distance) as cnt
from union_recordset ur
order by distance;
```

If not, you can count the *first* occurrence:

```
select ur.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by distance) as cnt
from (select ur.*,
             row_number() over (partition by company_id order by distance) as seqnum
      from union_recordset ur
     ) ur
order by distance;
```

In Postgres, the `sum()` can be simplified to:

```
       sum( (seqnum = 1)::int ) over (order by distance) as cnt
```

And then to get the numbers for, say, the first three companies, you want:

```
select ur.*
from (select ur.*,
             sum( (seqnum = 1)::int ) over (order by distance) as cnt
      from (select ur.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by company_id order by distance) as seqnum
            from union_recordset ur
           ) ur
     ) ur
where cnt <= 3
order by distance;
```

Comment: The subquery `select ur.*,
             row_number() over (partition by company_id order by distance) as seqnum
      from union_recordset ur` isn't returning ordered list by `distance`. It's ordering by `company_id` only and which is further causing issue with the parent query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RAJ . . . I don't understand.  The ordering in the subquery doesn't matter.  If you want results in a particular order, then use `order by` for the outer query.

Comment: @RAJ . . . You seem to have many, many companies that all have the same distance.  They are all counted at once.

Comment: My requirement is that they should be counted only once. Meaning, each company_id should be counted only once from the recordset ordered by distance.

Comment: @RAJ . . . Your data has thousands of companies all at exactly the same distance.  They are all being counted just once.  These look like test companies in your data, so perhaps you just want to filter them out.

Comment: Thanks, I did "ORDER BY distance, id" and seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick your companies then join it with itself agian to fetch other data:

```
select ur.* from union_recordset ur join
  (select distinct company_id from union_recordset order by distance limit 3) ur_d
  on (ur.company_id = ur_d.company_id)
```

Attention: The `Limit` command supported after PostgreSQL 8.1.